# Can I use GaussianProcessRegressor to interpolate in one dimension which preserves relation among other dims?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am new to using scikit-learn and am trying to implement the GaussianProcessRegressor class. I have an input 1D array X for the training set, but for my targets y I have essentially a 3D array (a, b, c) where a is the dimension I would like to interpolate over using GPR and which matches the length of X. I need to preserve the relation among b and c, however--they are not to be interpolated over (i.e. the GPR is 1D).

I have solved this problem using `make_interp_spline` from the `scipy.interpolate` class, writing `interp = make_interp_spline(X, y)`, and scipy knows to interpolate over the first axis and apply the same transformation to the others. I would like to see if GPR is more accurate than quintic or cubic splines for my particular set of data y.

Is it possible to do this sort of thing using the `sklearn.gaussian_process` class?

I already tried `gaussian_process.fit(X.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(len(X),-1))`, where now I have pushed all of b and c into the `n_targets` part of y, but I'm not sure if that is doing what I would like. Here is some example code:

```html
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Matern

X = np.linspace(1.5,4.5,13)
#y is an array of shape (13, 81, 6228), but collapse the last two dims
# to 81*6228 = 504468
y = np.arange(0,504468).reshape(13,-1)
kernel = 1. * Matern(length_scale=1., nu=2.5)
gaussian_process = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel,         n_restarts_optimizer=10)
gaussian_process.fit(X.reshape(-1, 1), y)
gaussian_process.predict(np.array([3.0]).reshape(1,-1))
```

Comment: "I have". "I have solved". "I already tried". Show us some code to help with what you've done so far!